# Conectar Base de Datos en Menu Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Necesito ayuda para conectar la base de datos a un menú creado en Java. El menú es sobre una tienda en la que se realiza un pedido y los productos se encuentran en una base de datos los cuales se podrán agregar al pedido según lo que el cliente desee. Lo que necesito es que los botones del menú se enlacen con la base de datos y den la función necesaria pero no se como hacerlo, ayúdenme por favor.

**Aqui esta el codigo de la conexion de la base de datos en java**

```
package pedido;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import static java.sql.JDBCType.NULL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class Pedido {

//Datos para la conexion con la base de datos
private String usuario = "root";
private String contraseña = "";
private String host = "localhost";
private String BD = "tiendajava";
private Connection con = null;

public Connection getConexionMYSQL() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        String servidor = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + "/" + BD;
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(servidor, usuario, contraseña);
        return con;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return con;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Inicio un objeto de la clase Pedido
    Pedido con = new Pedido();
    //Se llama al metodo
    Connection conexion = con.getConexionMYSQL();
    //comprobar que no sea nula la conexion
    if (conexion == null) {
        System.out.println("Error en la conexion");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Conexion Exitosa");
    }
    try {
        //Aqui van las consultas!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        System.out.println("Bienvenidos A mi tienda!!!!");

        //TAREA!!!!! PASAR EL QUERY POR UN SCANNER!!!!!!!!!
        String query = "insert into productos (name, price)" + " values (?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conexion.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStmt.setString(1, "srsrs");
        preparedStmt.setInt(2, 500);

        // execute the preparedstatement
        int rows = preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
        if (rows == 0) {
            System.out.println("No se pudo insertar en la tabla");
        } else {
            System.out.println("INSERT Exitoso");
        }
        //conexion.close(); siempre al final de las consultas

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Got an exception!");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM productos";
        PreparedStatement select = conexion.prepareStatement(selectQuery);
        java.sql.ResultSet rs = select.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            int cod = rs.getInt("cod");
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            int price = rs.getInt("price");

            System.out.println(cod + name + price);
        }

        conexion.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Got an exception!");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

**Aquí esta el código del menú en Java**

```
package pedido;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel; 
import Atxy2k.CustomTextField.RestrictedTextField;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class interfaz extends javax.swing.JFrame {
DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel();

public interfaz() {
    initComponents();
    model.addColumn("PRODUCTO");
    model.addColumn("MODELO");
    model.addColumn("CANTIDAD");
    model.addColumn("PRECIO");
    this.Tabla.setModel(model);

    RestrictedTextField restricted = new RestrictedTextField(campocedula);
    restricted.setLimit(8);
    restricted.setOnlyNums(true);

}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Agregar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Eliminar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Salir = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Guardar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane7 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    Tabla = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    camponombre = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    campodireccion = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    campocedula = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    campotelefono = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jSeparator3 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("PEDIDO RC");
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));
    setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(6, 6, 3, 3));
    setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));
    setIconImages(null);
    setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0));

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Showcard Gothic", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(162, 4, 75));
    jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel1.setText("REALICE SU PEDIDO");
    jLabel1.setToolTipText("");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft PhagsPa", 1, 16)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("DATOS DEL CLIENTE");

    jLabel3.setText("Nombre y Apellido:");

    jLabel4.setText("Dirección de Entrega:");

    jLabel5.setText("Cedúla:");

    jLabel6.setText("Telefono:");

    jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft PhagsPa", 1, 16)); // NOI18N
    jLabel7.setText("PRODUCTOS A PEDIR");

    Agregar.setBackground(javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults().getColor("FormattedTextField.selectionBackground"));
    Agregar.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pedido/añadirprod.png"))); // NOI18N
    Agregar.setBorder(null);
    Agregar.setBorderPainted(false);
    Agregar.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    Agregar.setFocusPainted(false);
    Agregar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            AgregarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Eliminar.setBackground(javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults().getColor("PasswordField.selectionBackground"));
    Eliminar.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pedido/borrarprod.png"))); // NOI18N
    Eliminar.setBorder(null);
    Eliminar.setBorderPainted(false);
    Eliminar.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    Eliminar.setFocusPainted(false);
    Eliminar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            EliminarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Salir.setBackground(java.awt.Color.gray);
    Salir.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pedido/salir.png"))); // NOI18N
    Salir.setBorder(null);
    Salir.setBorderPainted(false);
    Salir.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    Salir.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    Salir.setFocusPainted(false);
    Salir.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            SalirMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    Salir.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            SalirActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Guardar.setBackground(java.awt.Color.gray);
    Guardar.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pedido/guardar (2).png"))); // NOI18N
    Guardar.setBorder(null);
    Guardar.setBorderPainted(false);
    Guardar.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    Guardar.setFocusPainted(false);
    Guardar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            GuardarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Tabla.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
    Tabla.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane7.setViewportView(Tabla);

    camponombre.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
    camponombre.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
    camponombre.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            camponombreActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    camponombre.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            camponombreKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });

    campodireccion.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
    campodireccion.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
    campodireccion.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            campodireccionKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });

    campocedula.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
    campocedula.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
    campocedula.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            campocedulaActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    campocedula.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            campocedulaKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });

    campotelefono.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
    campotelefono.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
    campotelefono.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            campotelefonoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    campotelefono.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            campotelefonoKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel9.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.TOP);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jLabel9)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(12, 12, 12)
            .addComponent(jLabel10)
            .addGap(153, 153, 153)
            .addComponent(jLabel1))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(12, 12, 12)
            .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 628, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(12, 12, 12)
            .addComponent(jLabel2))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addGap(28, 28, 28)
            .addComponent(camponombre, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 260, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
            .addComponent(jLabel5)
            .addGap(91, 91, 91)
            .addComponent(campocedula, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 156, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(349, 349, 349)
            .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 255, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
            .addComponent(jLabel4)
            .addGap(12, 12, 12)
            .addComponent(campodireccion, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 435, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
            .addComponent(jLabel6)
            .addGap(81, 81, 81)
            .addComponent(campotelefono, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 156, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(12, 12, 12)
            .addComponent(jSeparator3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 628, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(12, 12, 12)
            .addComponent(jLabel7))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(38, 38, 38)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 488, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(46, 46, 46)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(Agregar)
                .addComponent(Eliminar)))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(146, 146, 146)
            .addComponent(Guardar)
            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
            .addComponent(Salir, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 167, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLabel9)
            .addGap(2, 2, 2)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                    .addComponent(jLabel10))
                .addComponent(jLabel1))
            .addGap(12, 12, 12)
            .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(6, 6, 6)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addGap(12, 12, 12)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(2, 2, 2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addComponent(camponombre, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(16, 16, 16)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(2, 2, 2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5))
                .addComponent(campocedula, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(17, 17, 17)
            .addComponent(jLabel8)
            .addGap(8, 8, 8)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(2, 2, 2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                .addComponent(campodireccion, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(2, 2, 2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6))
                .addComponent(campotelefono, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(34, 34, 34)
            .addComponent(jSeparator3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(6, 6, 6)
            .addComponent(jLabel7)
            .addGap(12, 12, 12)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(Agregar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                    .addComponent(Eliminar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(Guardar)
                .addComponent(Salir)))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void AgregarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

}                                       

private void EliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int eli=Tabla.getSelectedRowCount();
    if(eli>0){
        model.removeRow(eli);
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay productos que eliminar");
    }     
}                                        

private void SalirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    System.exit(0);
}                                     

private void GuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                       

private void SalirMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   

}                                  

private void campocedulaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void campotelefonoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

}                                             

private void camponombreActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void campocedulaKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
    char validar=evt.getKeyChar();
    if (Character.isLetter(validar)){
        getToolkit().beep();
        evt.consume();
    }

}                                    

private void campotelefonoKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
    char validar=evt.getKeyChar();
    if (Character.isLetter(validar)){
        getToolkit().beep();
        evt.consume();
    }
}                                      

private void camponombreKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
    char validar=evt.getKeyChar();

    if(Character.isDigit(validar)){
        getToolkit().beep();
        evt.consume();
    }
}                                    

private void campodireccionKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        

}                                       

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new interfaz().setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton Agregar;
private javax.swing.JButton Eliminar;
private javax.swing.JButton Guardar;
private javax.swing.JButton Salir;
private javax.swing.JTable Tabla;
private javax.swing.JTextField campocedula;
private javax.swing.JTextField campodireccion;
private javax.swing.JTextField camponombre;
private javax.swing.JTextField campotelefono;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane7;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator3;
// End of variables declaration                   

}
```

**Tambien dejo una imagen de la interfaz del menú del pedido**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la parte del carrito de añadir es donde se tiene que seleccionar el producto de la base de datos lo contrario del de restar que es eliminar un producto seleccionado del pedido.
En el botón de guardar que guarde el pedido junto a los datos del cliente seria en una base de datos también.

Answer (score 3):

Te faltó el puerto en este código. En este caso puse el 3306, pero si el mysql ocupa otro, debes ponerlo. Aquí hay una muestra:

```
String servidor = "jdbc:mysql://"+host+":3306/"+BD;
```

Esto es para conectarse a la base de datos.

Crea un método con los datos de conexión y en el evento de Button realiza la función de insertar, actualizar y eliminar, de acuerdo a qué función quieres.

En este método:

```
private void GuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    theQuery("insert into productos (name, price) values('"+camponombre.getText()+"','"+campoprecio.getText()"')");
}
```

Y el método:

```
public void theQuery(String query){
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/tiendajava","root","");
        st = con.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(query);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Query Executed");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Pues tengo flojera de ver todo tu código, la idea es trabajar con la metodología de MVC.

Según tengo entendido quieres llenar la tabla que se muestra en tu interfaz, y ya tienes la parte que obtiene los datos suponiendo que lo hace correcto. Lo ideal sería que guardaras esos datos en un arreglo o en una lista y de ahí pasarlos a tu tabla.

La forma de hacerlo en java es crear un `DefaultTableModel`. Tienes que ir guardando tus datos en un arreglo. Por ejemplo:

```
string [] fila = new string[3];
fila[0]="producto";
fila[1]="id";
fila[2]="precio";
```

Después agregarlo al model (`model.addRow(fila);`). Y cuando termines de cargar todos los datos al model, cargar el model a tu tabla (`tabla.setModel(model);`).

Con eso se visualizan los datos en tu interfaz.